# Spacing between two bootstrap controls isn't working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to make this:

[image]

And I wrote this:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                    @Html.Label("Name", new {@class = ".control-label"})
                    @Html.DropDownList("nameadmin", new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(77881, 5)), new {@class = "dropdown"})

                    @Html.CheckBox("ShowEmailInFooter", new {@class = "checkbox-inline  col-sm-offset-4"})
                    @Html.Label("Show Email in Footer", new {@class = ".control-label"})
                </div>
            </div>
```

But It made it look like this:

[image]

See it doesn't have the spacing. How can I fix ?

Comment: Have you tried to put `.row` on your second div?

Comment: @WellingtonZanelli ok I tried it, it took those last two to a NEXT row,  not inline anymore.

Comment: ok, so my gues is to put the `col-sm-*` in every element in your code, distributing they into one line. I can't test it now to put it as answer, sorry.

Comment: Ok I put a span between them  <span class="col-sm-offset-1"></span> but don't know if it a good design or not.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want something more like this to get the style you want. I've not positive on what the generated html looks like, but I believe this will get you on the right track.

```
<div class="row>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">    
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Name", new {@class = ".control-label"})
            @Html.DropDownList("nameadmin", new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(77881, 5)), new {@class = "dropdown"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">    
        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.CheckBox("ShowEmailInFooter", new {@class = "checkbox-inline"})
           @Html.Label("Show Email in Footer", new {@class = ".control-label"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap also has styles for inline forms.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Name", new {@class = ".control-label"})
        @Html.DropDownList("nameadmin", new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(77881, 5)), new {@class = "dropdown"})
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        @Html.CheckBox("ShowEmailInFooter", new {@class = "checkbox-inline"})
        @Html.Label("Show Email in Footer", new {@class = ".control-label"})
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, first one looks better. Should I make sure they add up to 12? currently I have col-sm-offset-2 + col-sm-6 + col-sm-4  ?